# Order Query in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Trying to modify a Django project's filter.

I have the following query

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(public=True)
```

I want to modify this to have the query ordered by 'like_count'

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), like this:

```
q = Post.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('like_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Like` is a different table.

The solution in the below link might help.

[Django, annotation and ordering using data from other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743766/django-annotation-and-ordering-using-data-from-other-table)