# Django annotation using data from another table without relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

What I'm trying to do is annotate a queryset with information from a few tables that don't have foreign key relations between them, but can be identified from values in the main table. I realise that I could add relations and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743766/django-annotation-and-ordering-using-data-from-other-table), but the db I'm using doesn't allow for relations.

So given models:

```
class DailyShopData(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.IntegerField()
    currency = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shop_id', 'date', 'currency')

class DailyUserData(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.IntegerField()
    currency = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()
    unique_users = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shop_id', 'date', 'currency')
```

We can relate the two fields via the `('shop_id', 'data_date', 'currency')` key.

So what I'd like to do for my annotation is:

```
daily_shop_data_queryset.objects.values('shop_id').annotate(
    shop_amount=Sum("amount"),
    shop_unique_users=Sum(???)  
)
```

So that the result would be aggregated `amount` and `unique_users` per `shop_id`.

Comment: Its a bit confusing, You get total amount in a shop, in a single day in `shop_amount` what do you want from the `shop_unique_users`? Is it a list of `unique_user` id's??

Comment: I'd like a sum of the number of `unique_user` per day.